# Cannot update my nlme model using varPower or other varClasses

Tags: r

I have fit a model using nlme and I don't think the residuals look good enough, so I am trying a transformation by

```
fit.nlme6 <- update(fit.nlme5, weights = varPower())
```

I get `Error: Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1`.  I have tried other classes that I don't think make much sense anyway and tried various `forms = ~` and `fixed`.  All with the same error message, sometimes with bonus warning messages.

Here are the residuals. I think `varPower` should work perfectly, so why doesn't it?

residuals:

[image]

More information, `fit.nlme5` is a model fit to a beta growth function that has three parameters, `w.max` (maximum biomass), `t.e` (moment growth ends), and `t.m` (moment of maximum growth).  The model looks like this

```
fit.nlme5 <- update(fit.nlme4, fixed = list(t.e ~ trt + ground + trt:ground, w.max + t.m ~ 1),
                start = c(cfsTD[1:4], rep(0,2) ,cfsTD[5:6]))
```

There are three treatments (trt) in two locations (ground).  After the residuals get fixed, I'll run some contrasts to compare the treatments in the different locations.

Here is the data https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21080842/cobsgddv8.txt

And the code one would need to get to the final model:

```
  #You'll need these functions
## Implementing the beta growth function from (Yin et al 2003)

bgfInit <- function(mCall, LHS, data){

  xy <- sortedXyData(mCall[["time"]], LHS, data)
  if(nrow(xy) < 4){
    stop("Too few distinct input values to fit a bgf")
  }
  w.max <- max(xy[,"y"])
  t.e <- NLSstClosestX(xy, w.max)
  t.m <- NLSstClosestX(xy, w.max/2)
  value <- c(w.max, t.e, t.m)
  names(value) <- mCall[c("w.max","t.e","t.m")]
  value

}


bgf <- function(time, w.max, t.e, t.m){

  .expr1 <- t.e / (t.e - t.m)
  .expr2 <- (time/t.e)^.expr1
  .expr3 <- (1 + (t.e - time)/(t.e - t.m))
  .value <- w.max * .expr3 * .expr2

  ## Derivative with respect to t.e
  .exp1 <- ((time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e - t.m))) * ((t.e-time)/(t.e-t.m) + 1)
  .exp2 <- (log(time/t.e)*((1/(t.e-t.m) - (t.e/(t.e-t.m)^2) - (1/(t.e - t.m)))))*w.max
  .exp3 <- (time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e-t.m))
  .exp4 <- w.max * ((1/(t.e-t.m)) - ((t.e - time)/(t.e-t.m)^2))
  .exp5 <- .exp1 * .exp2 + .exp3 * .exp4 

  ## Derivative with respect to t.m
  .ex1 <- t.e * (time/t.e)^((t.e/(t.e - t.m))) * log(time/t.e) * ((t.e - time)/(t.e -      
t.m) + 1) * w.max
  .ex2 <- (t.e - time) * w.max * (time/t.e)^(t.e/(t.e-t.m))
  .ex3 <- (t.e - t.m)^2
  .ex4 <- .ex1 / .ex3 + .ex2 / .ex3

  .actualArgs <- as.list(match.call()[c("w.max", "t.e", "t.m")])

##  Gradient
  if (all(unlist(lapply(.actualArgs, is.name)))) {
    .grad <- array(0, c(length(.value), 3L), list(NULL, c("w.max", 
                                                      "t.e", "t.m")))
    .grad[, "w.max"] <- .expr3 * .expr2
    .grad[, "t.e"] <- .exp5
    .grad[, "t.m"] <- .ex4 
    dimnames(.grad) <- list(NULL, .actualArgs)
    attr(.value, "gradient") <- .grad
  }
    .value
}

SSbgf <- selfStart(bgf, initial = bgfInit, c("w.max", "t.e", "t.m"))

#Now for the data and fitting
grow<-read.table("cobsgddv8.txt", header=T)

library(nlme)

grow10<-subset(grow, grow$year == "2010")
grow10$EU<- with(grow10, factor(ground):factor(plot))
grow10G<-groupedData(mass ~ gdd | EU, data=grow10)

fit.beta.10 <- nlsList(mass ~ SSbgf(gdd, w.max, t.e, t.m), data = grow10G)

fit.nlme.10<-nlme(fit.beta.10, random=pdDiag(w.max ~1))

cfs <- fixef(fit.nlme.10)
fit.nlme2 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(t.e ~ trt, w.max + t.m ~ 1),
                    start = c(cfs[2], rep(0,2), cfs[c(1,3)]))

cfsT <- fixef(fit.nlme2)


fit.nlme3 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(t.e ~ ground, w.max + t.m ~ 1),
                    start = c(cfs[2], rep(0,1), cfs[c(1,3)]))

cfsG <- fixef(fit.nlme3)

fit.nlme4 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(t.e ~ trt + ground, w.max + t.m ~ 1),
                    start = c(cfsT[1:2], cfsG[1:2], cfs[c(1,3)]))

cfsTD <- fixef(fit.nlme4)

fit.nlme5 <- update(fit.nlme4, fixed = list(t.e ~ trt + ground + trt:ground, w.max +     
t.m ~ 1),
                    start = c(cfsTD[1:4], rep(0,2) ,cfsTD[5:6]))


fit.nlme6 <- update(fit.nlme5, weights = varPower())
```

Comment: More information would help solve this question. Without knowing the structure of the data or what fit.nlme5 is you are unlikely to get a good (or any) answer.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I added some more information and hopefully it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, this is not enough information. Since so many points are close to zero, you should give

```
varConstPower(power=0.5,fixed=list(const=10))
```

a try, and play with the offset.

Comment: Thanks, @Dieter, I added some information.  Is there anything else that would be helpful?  I am playing with the offset now, but no luck yet.

Comment: The most important missing link is the data set, because nlme strongly depends on the data. Try dput, and give a self-contained example, i.e. one that can be run when pasted into R.

Comment: Okay, @Dieter, I hesitated to inlude the code because it gets a bit lengthy with the functions you'll need, but you asked for it!  I attached the data too.  You should see what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Nazer: Getting closer, and it looks good in general. However, the program does not run, because your forgot to include how fit.nlme.10 is computed (the most important one). Please check your sample in a fresh window, and trim it down to the absolute necessary to show, which means that you only show fit.nlme5 explicitly (work) and nmle (fails). I had similar cases before, and sometimes you can solve the problem by adding a minor offset (0.001) to your independent data to avoid singularities.